# changing data from json on button click React-Native

Tags: json, react-native

I'm rather new to React-native and i've been trying to show sort and show some api data.
I have the following json data which is displayed in a SectionList:

```
[
{ 
  key:Animals
  shown: true
  data: [{....}]
}
{
  key: Anime
  shown: true
  data: [{....}]
}
.....
]
```

My desire is that when i press a certain button for each Category of items (this case they "key" value), their "shown" boolean changes states, and therefore the whole section goes hidden.

Other info: I render each button in renderSectionHeader

Full Code:

```
export default class BasicFlatList extends Component<Props> {

//constructor setting states
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = ({
        deletedRowKey: null,
        loading: true,
        link: 'https://api.publicapis.org/entries',
        data: []
    });
}

componentDidMount(){

    return fetch(this.state.link)
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((responseJson) => {

            this.setState({
                data: responseJson.entries,
            }, function () {

                console.tron.log('date', this.state.data)

                groups = _.groupBy(this.state.data, d => d.Category);

                console.tron.log('gruping', groups);

                groups = _.reduce(groups, (acc, next, index) => {
                    acc.push({
                        title: index,
                        shown: true,
                        data: next
                    });
                    return acc
                }, []);

                console.tron.log('reducing', groups);
                this.setState({
                    loading: false,
                    groups,
                })
            });
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.error(error);
        })

}

//functions
//function for rendering in the separator between each element
renderSeparator = () => {
    return (
        <View style={styles.separator}/>
    )
};

//function for rendering in the header
renderHeader = () => {
    return (<View style={styles.header}>
        <Text style={styles.headertext}>Organized APIs</Text>
    </View>)
};

//function for rendering in each item
renderItem = (item) => {
    return <ListItem APIname={item.item.API} APIdescription={item.item.Description} url={item.item.Link} shown={item.section.shown}/>
};

//function for rendering in each section
renderSectionHeader = (headerItem) => {
    return (
        <View style={{flex:1, flexDirection:'row'}}>
            <Text adjustFontSizeToFit numberOfLines={1} allowFontScaling
                  style={styles.sectionheader}>{headerItem.section.title}</Text>
            <Button unpressedText={'Show'} pressedText={'Hide'} style={styles.buton} />
        </View>

    )
};


//main render part
render(){
    return (
        <View style={{flex: 1}}>
            {this.state.loading && <Loading/>}
            {!this.state.loading &&
            <View style={{flex: 1}}>
                <View style={styles.topbar}/>
                <SectionList
                    ListHeaderComponent={this.renderHeader}
                    SectionSeparatorComponent={this.renderSeparator}
                    sections={this.state.groups}
                    renderItem={this.renderItem}
                    renderSectionHeader={(headerItem, index) => this.renderSectionHeader(headerItem, index)}
                    keyExtractor={(item, index) => index}
                    stickySectionHeadersEnabled={true}
                    initialNumToRneder={15}
                    removeCLippedSubviews={true}
                />
            </View>
            }
        </View>
    );
}
```

}

Comment: do you have seperate button for each key ?

Comment: each section is indexed and has a different button yes

Comment: can you please provide the complete code?

Comment: Will do that as soon as i get home :)

Comment: i edited the post not to overflow the comments. i think this is what you are looking for, the rest are just some components with styles inside them. The buttons act individual and as of now the onPress is built inside the Button component but that can change if needed. Edit: if you need the rest of the code i can provide it